# Adding a class type to database

Tags: c#, database, class, sqlcommand

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public string SurName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfDeath { get; set; }

    public Gender gender { get; set; }

    public Person Father { get; set; }

    public Person Mother { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add father and mother to the database trough a query.

```
create table Persons(
    PersonId int primary key identity,
    SurName nvarchar(50) not null,
    LastName nvarchar(50) not null,
    DateOfBirth date not null,
    DateOfDeath date null,
    Gender tinyint not null,
    Father ??nvarchar(50) null,
    Mother ??varchar(50) null
);
```

I don't know what to use as type. And can't find it anywhere else.

```
public void InsertPerson(Person person)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand =
             new SqlCommand("insert into Persons values (@surName, @lastName, @dateOfBirth, @dateOfDeath, @gender, @father, @mother);", sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surName", person.SurName);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", person.LastName);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOfBirth", person.DateOfBirth);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOfDeath", person.DateOfDeath);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", person.gender);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@father", person.Father);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mother", person.Mother);

            sqlConnection.Open();

            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Eventually I want to add the values in the database. And if it's right so far. I assume it's not and gonna ask already.
I'm still in school and having difficulties without my teacher. Thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: You would need a foreign key, essentially the Mother and Father columns will be primary keys to other `Persons`

Comment: Any error returns when running this code? if there is, show the error in here. and why you need to use this `public Person Father { get; set; }
        public Person Mother { get; set; }` instead of using a normal datatype like `public string Father`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should re-design `Person` class to have a `foreign key` to reference.

Looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public string SurName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfDeath { get; set; }

    public Gender gender { get; set; }

    public int FatherId { get; set; }

    public int MotherId { get; set; }

 }
```

Then your table in the database looks like this

```
create table Persons(
    PersonId int primary key identity,
    SurName nvarchar(50) not null,
    LastName nvarchar(50) not null,
    DateOfBirth date not null,
    DateOfDeath date null,
    Gender tinyint not null,
    FatherId int  null,
    MotherId int  null
);
```

and change this 
from:

```
public Person Father { get; set; }

public Person Mother { get; set; }
```

To:

```
   public int Father { get; set; }

    public int Mother { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to work any further if I would make father or mother a int. Since Mother and Father are still a person.  I am creating a Family tree program where eventually they need to be able to see who there mother father niece etc. is .

@Vijunav Vastivch
    `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query '(@surName nvarchar(5),@lastName nvarchar(6),@dateOfBirth datetim' expects the parameter '@father', which was not supplied.`'

Comment: Did you check my answer?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59559338/9071943

Answer (score 0):

Why you need `??` when creating a table like this:

```
 create table Persons(
        PersonId int primary key identity,
        SurName nvarchar(50) not null,
        LastName nvarchar(50) not null,
        DateOfBirth date not null,
        DateOfDeath date null,
        Gender tinyint not null,
        Father ??nvarchar(50) null,
        Mother ??varchar(50) null
    );

Just remove it:
create table Persons(
    PersonId int primary key identity,
    SurName nvarchar(50) not null,
    LastName nvarchar(50) not null,
    DateOfBirth date not null,
    DateOfDeath date null,
    Gender tinyint not null,
    Father nvarchar(50) null,
    Mother varchar(50) null
);
```

Answer (score 0):

And this is the proper way of Setting up the Sql Connection:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand =
             new SqlCommand("insert into Persons values (@surName, @lastName, @dateOfBirth, @dateOfDeath, @gender, @father, @mother);", sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surName", person.SurName);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", person.LastName);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOfBirth", person.DateOfBirth);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOfDeath", person.DateOfDeath);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", person.gender);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@father", person.Father);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mother", person.Mother);



            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```